# Change CSS on element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm new to frontend development, and I want to rezize an `<img>` with JavaScript:

Which element?

```html
<div class="dz-image">
    <img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="principal.png" src="http://localhost:49407/file/Image/660">
</div>
```

What function im using in js?

```js
this.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "http://localhost:11111/file/Image/" + principal)
    { document.querySelector('data-dz-thumbnail') };
```

I'm using `querySelector` to get the spefic `<img>` element.

Is it possible to add some style directly on that line like `height:120; width: 120;`?

Comment: You have mentioned nothing about what issue are you having with current code? Also, what is `this.emit` & `mockFile` here?

Comment: I doubt if this itself works `document.querySelector('data-dz-thumbnail')`

Comment: This is working but i want to change size of the img.   this (dropzone or drag and drop) has an event called emit when creates that div. mockfile is a simulated file on javascript based on a file stored on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,it is  possible to add some style directly.

```
let ele = document.querySelector('[data-dz-thumbnail]')
ele.style.width="120px"
ele.style.height="120px"
```

Comment: It looks like the correct answer, however img size still the same. (im not sure if this is for another reason)

Comment: It is working for me. can host your code in jsfiddle or some where @gaccerboni

Comment: This  fix my problem on the img but changes all the others that shouldnt: 'code'                         $('div.content img').css('width', '120');
                        $('div.content img').css('height', '120'); 'code'

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, `queryselector` should be `classname`, id or tag

Second you can add css by taking a variable for your `querySelector` line.  It is like:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div'); 
el.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
el.style.display = 'none';
el.style['border-radius'] = '5px';
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using jQuery's [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method like this:

```
$('[data-dz-thumbnail]').css('width', '120');
$('[data-dz-thumbnail]').css('height', '120');
```